# How to keep smooth surface?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to make the following shape round with subdiv modifier. After adding supporting edges, I get a sharp edge (image below). My question is, how do I can get rid of it so I can keep an evenly smooth surface?

Before subdiv:
[image]

After subdiv:
[image]

Topology with subdiv:
[image]

Image reference:
[image]

Result of using LoopTools:
[image]

Comment: Hello, do you have an image of the object you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I just added the image reference. It doesn't reveal the area I'm working on but I imagine that it would appear to be smooth

Comment: Does `Shade Smooth` work for you?

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is smooth shaded.

Comment: Do you want the faces on the side to be aligned? (if so, you can achieve this via `LoopTools`->`Flatten`)

Comment: Hmm, not exactly sure what you mean. Do you mean do I want the side faces to be equally smooth? If yes, then I do. If not, could you clarify a bit more?

Comment: I just tried the LoopTools and it does work. I guess the sharp edge happens because the faces weren't evenly flat since I scaled the tail inward. Updated my post to show the result.