# How to remove a crease to keep a smooth surface?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, smooth

I want to remove the crease shown on the surface below. I did ask this question [before](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/309261/176540) and while I thought I got the solution, the situation has changed a bit. The previous suggestion was to use the LoopTool to flatten the face. It did work but I realize it removed the curve I want to maintain. Any idea how I should approach this?

Update: For future reference, if anyone has any creases shown in their mesh, it's likely your topology that needs to be fixed.

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
I added some references. The curve I mentioned refers to the curvature of the outer rim from the reference photos. Note how the transition from the top to the bottom is curving in making the bottom smaller. That's the curve I would like to maintain.

The shape I'm trying to create:

Reference 1)
[image]

Reference 2)
[image]

Reference 3)
[image]

Crease (side view):

[image]

The curve (top view):

[image]

Topology:
[image]

Blender file:
[image]

Comment: We don't know how the shape is supposed to look like. ok, you want to remove the indicated crease, but which other parts are supposed to be maintained or not?

Comment: Sorry about that. I added some references. The curve I mentioned is referring to the curvature of the outer rim from the reference photos . Note how the transition from the top to the bottom is curving in making the bottom smaller. That's the curve I would like to maintain. 

Let me know if this clears it up. If not, I might probably vote to delete this post since it's hard to describe the situation clearly via a post.

Comment: Could you please make a drawing of the shape you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi there, that's actually a good idea. I think Niklas' solution is the one I'm looking for so I might not need to draw the shape anymore. Will update my post with a drawing if I need further assistance but I will use this idea for any arbitrary shape next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to your problem lies in the topology. I tried some things and got something I assume you tried to achieve.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Just in case you want to examine the modified model, heres the blend file:
[image]

Comment: Hey there, that looks like what I need! Let me open your file and examine further. Can't seem to open your file right now since your Blender is on 4.0. and I'm on 3.4

Comment: Happy to hear that.

Comment: Yep, that worked. I modified the topology a bit more since I can still see a bit of the crease when using Matcap shading. It's looking real smooth now! Thanks for the help.